# How can I create an EditorTemplate for an enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I have a model with an `enum`

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Unspecified
}

public class FooClass
{
    public Gender UserGender {set; get;}
}
```

Since this `Gender` might be used in other classes, I wanted to create an EditorTemplate for it and ask for an editor in the create/edit view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserGender)
```

After that I created a partial view located in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Gender.cshtml`. In the template I added something just for testing like:

```
@model TestProject.Models.Entity.Gender
@Html.TextBox("")
```

or

```
@model TestProject.Models.Entity.Gender
Hello...
```

but all I get is an Exception:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'TestProject.Models.Entity.Gender'.

Is this how Editor Templates work or I'm completely off track?

**edit:**

If I delete the template file (`Gender.cshtml`) I am getting a textfield as editor, and no exception is thrown.

Also, this is for a `Create` view and in the controller I pass no object to it. I just call `return View();`

Comment: Your model `FooClass` is most probably null.

Comment: can you provide view and controller action?

Comment: @Mathew Most likely since it is in a Create view. Should I pass a new instance of the model in the view?
Also, could you provide how an enum EditorTemplate should be?

Comment: @odyodyodys in Create view use default value of model with default value of fields

Comment: @Grundy thank you. If I create the default editor for Gender, I'm getting a Textfield for the enum.

Comment: That is the default editor template for primitive types.

Comment: also you can use `Nullable<TestProject.Models.Entity.Gender>`

Comment: @Grundy had forgotten this. Thank you. Could you provide a sample on how I can create an EditorTemplate? Something to get me started

Comment: @odyodyodys are you try code in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
@model Nullable<TestProject.Models.Entity.Gender>
@Html.ListBox("lb", Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestProject.Models.Entity.Gender)).Cast<TestProject.Models.Entity.Gender>().Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected=i==Model }))
```